# Where to get models with weights instead of only weights? What's the purpose of .h5 files?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, pretraining

I have downloaded `.h5` files from [qubvel/resnet](https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models/releases/tag/0.0.1) and [qubvel/efficientnet](https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet/releases/tag/v0.0.1). I was trying to use some models as a backbone for my model but I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: No model found in the config file.
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829324/error-while-importing-vgg16-h5-file-valueerror-no-model-found-in-config-file) this is because the `.h5` file contains only weights, not a model.

So those `.h5` files are only weights. What's the purpose of having only weights without architecture?

I was trying to do following code:

```
resnet18_path_to_file = "models/resnet18.h5"
resnet18 = tf.keras.models.load_model(resnet18_path_to_file)
resnet18.compile()

inputs = resnet18.input
outputs = resnet18.layers[-2].output

return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="custom_resnet18")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options when saving and loading a keras model, as explained at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize:

- **save the whole configuration**, including the architecture, weights and even the last training state
- **but also** the model **architecture and** the **weights** can be **saved as independent files**, and that is what you might have loaded: an .h5 with only the weights, and you also need the .json with the model architecture, based on the snippet below:

-model architecture and model weights to disk as separate files, which is what it might be done by the user who trained the model:

```
json_config = model.to_json()
with open('model_config.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_config)
# weights saving to disk
model.save_weights('path_to_my_weights.h5')
```

So you need to do the following:

-load the model as follows (you need the model json also):

```
with open('model_config.json') as json_file:
    json_config = json_file.read()
new_model = keras.models.model_from_json(json_config)
new_model.load_weights('path_to_my_weights.h5')
```